# Android: how to search CSV file or ArrayList and return appropriate results?

Tags: android, search

I have recently added a SearchView in my app. Now what? It seems like a lot of Android tutorials about the SearchView explain nothing about anything.

I want to make a search function in my app that reads from an ArrayList of Buildings (a class in my app) that allows for a user to search from both the full and short names of the building and return the top 5 closest matches. However, I have no idea where to start. The classes in the ArrayList were read using a CSV file.

Essentially, I want to have a SearchView that searches the String values in an ArrayList for specific matching strings. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have another `ArrayList` of where the search result will be stored. you can try this

```
    ArrayList<String> storedContent = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> contentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String searchText = "sometest";
    for(String each : storedContent){
        if (each.contains(searchText)){
            contentArray.add(each);
        }
    }

    ListView displaySearchResult = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_id);
    myListAdapter adapter = new myListAdapter(contentArray, this) ;
    displaySearchResult.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

you can also use `each.matches(searchText)` instead of the `each.contains(searchText)` function.

the login is just that, loop through each content in the `csv` file or `arraylist` and test if the `text`(search query) matches part of the string in the `arraylist` or `csv` file.

Comment: Thanks. I'd also like to know if I need to create a second activity and XML layout to use the SearchView, or if this search can be done within the main activity.

Comment: its can be done in the main activity. its depends on you though

Answer (score 0):

If you've read the CSV file to a string, you can add it to an `ArrayList` like so:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(csvString.split(","));
```